# Unable to connect to SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to use the ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool. When I click on the Security, I kept getting this message.

> There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused
>   by an invalid server name or credentials, or by insufficient
>   permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not
>   being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page where
>   you can choose a new data store.

The following message may help in diagnosing the problem:

> Unable to connect to SQL Server database.

First of, which SQL Server does this administration tool trying to connect too? How do I change the "Current User Name" to other user name? It's automatically used my Windows authentication logged on user name. If I can change this and the password, it might just work.

Answer (score 0):

Your web.config has a connection string.  See this question for the full details on how to change that:
[ASP.NET Website Administration Tool: Unable to connect to SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277866/asp-net-website-administration-tool-unable-to-connect-to-sql-server-database?rq=1)